# How to create an algorithm to find the shortest cycle containing an edge?

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

Hi so I'm working on a review for my algorithms class and I'm having trouble with one of the questions on the review. I really don't even know where to begin with it, so anything will help. Thanks!

---

### Question

Describe an algorithm to find the shortest cycle containing a given edge e = (u,v) in a directed graph with positive edge lengths. If no cycle containing e exists, the algorithm should determine so. Algorithm should run in O(|v|^2)

---

### Progressing Solution:

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea to get you started would be to use DFS (Depth First Search) on the graph along with keeping a track of all the nodes you have been visiting using a vector to keep track of nodes currently in recursion loop. If you visit a node which is present in recursion vector, then there is a cycle. To get length of the cycle, you can check the length of the recursion vector. However, this need not be the smallest cycle, so don't terminate your algorithm. Choose the minimum of all the values you get after applying this algorithm to the entire graph.

I may have skipped over some important details, but they are for you to figure out.

For more help, refer to this link: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/